# Getting image size from XWPF document (Apache POI)

Tags: apache, parsing, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

anyone had experience parsing docx file with Apache poi?
while extracting image from `CharacterRun` using

```
paragraph.getRun().getEmbeddedPictures();
```

I was not able to find a way to get scaling or/and width/hight data of picture.

Is there functionality for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Figured that out!

I am not sure if that's the official way, but, here is how you can do it.

XWPFRun doesnot specifically give you any info, but
XWPFPicture, has method called, getCTPicture which will return an XML part of picture in docx file, using your favorite XML parser, all you need is to find this 
"/xml-fragment/pic:spPr/a:xfrm/a:ext" (xpath) in XML structure, that tag will have cx and cy attributes, these are basically the display width and height of image in EMU's English Metric Units.
If you google, you can find that EMUS_PER_INCH = 914400 so you can convert this to inches 
(or then later convert inches to pixels, if I am not mistaken should be 96 pixels per inch)
so doing some calculation you can figure out the new width and height of picture.

Kinda complicated, but it is what it is. And it works.

Hope that will help to someone.

Comment: It's just AWESOME! thanks a lot, Avetis, you saved my day!  This works perfectly: `picture.getCTPicture().getSpPr().getXfrm().getExt().getCx()` (the same for Cy) . Then we don't even need to use things like `Units.toEMU()` or `Units.toPoints`, as the method `run.addPicture()` takes the width and height (4th and 5th arguments) in EMU format.

Comment: Yep, and I remember I got crazy on this, so great it saved some time for you. there are so many terrible issues with this ahead though, so good luck :D

Comment: docx is not at all an "open" format, so it has probably been a tough task for Apache guys to create a tool like POI, but stillm it's very poorly documented. One could tell "so what's the problem? go and contribute!", but i really hope we all will forget docx as a nightmare :-)